# NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available kinetic 4.3.3

Tags: kineticjs

I get this errormessage
and have no clue where to look for.
Its on firefox 18.02
firebug says its on:
kinetic.min.js (Line 1)
Version 4.3.3

Thx for any hint in advance.

Comment: you need to show some other code, cause no one else knows either, especially since your kineticjs is the .min.js version

Comment: I would venture to guess that you have a component created which is not part of kineticJS

Answer (score 1):

You have an uncaught exception when you draw something on canvas.

Change your kinetic.min.js to `http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.3-beta.js` ONLY for debugging, then wrap  your code with try/catch to catch the error.

```
try {
  .... your code here ....
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.trace();
}
```